# Why is the timm visual transformer position embedding initializing to zeros?

Tags: pytorch, vision, transformer-model

I'm looking at the `timm` implementation of visual transformers and for the positional embedding, he is initializing his position embedding with zeros as follows:

```
self.pos_embed = nn.Parameter(torch.zeros(1, num_patches + 1, embed_dim))
```

See here:
https://github.com/rwightman/pytorch-image-models/blob/master/timm/models/vision_transformer.py#L309

I'm not sure how this actually embeds anything about the position when it is later added to the patch?

```
x = x + self.pos_embed
```

Any feedback is appreciated.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The positional embedding is a parameter that gets included in the computational graph and gets updated during training. So, it doesn't matter if you initialize with zeros; they are learned during training.

Answer (score 0):

If you check the repository now, it is indeed initialised using weights sampled from a normal distribution. It is very common to initialise the weights using zeros and then re-initialise inside an `init_weights` function. This is likely the case for the file version you looked at.

When using learnable position embeddings, they should indeed be initialised randomly. This is to help to the network learn the positional information of tokens. I have not seen zero initialisation used before, and this, at best, may impact model convergence.